# Access Elastic Search Using Its Java Api's

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to follow the Documentation of Elastic Search to get and post data from it using its java Api's. But i am constantly getting error.

This is the code i have tried as of now.

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("twitter", "tweet").build();
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));

GetResponse response = client.prepareGet("twitter", "tweet", "1").get();
```

The stack trace

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedMap
>         at com.c1x.entity.Test.main(Test.java:20)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedMap
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         ... 1 more

Please Help , i am new to Elastic search , the data is present in elastic search as i can see it when i use dev tools in kibana

after adding google commons

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/util/SetOnce
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.<init>(Settings.java:676)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.<clinit>(Settings.java:671)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings.<clinit>(Settings.java:84)
    at com.c1x.entity.Test.main(Test.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.util.SetOnce
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

After adding lucene jar

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
    at org.elasticsearch.common.Strings.<clinit>(Strings.java:459)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.build(Settings.java:1215)
    at com.c1x.entity.Test.main(Test.java:21)
```

Another error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty3Plugin overrides final method onModule.(Lorg/elasticsearch/common/network/NetworkModule;)V
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<clinit>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:84)
    at com.c1x.entity.Test.main(Test.java:22)
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss the `google-collections.jar` in your classpath. Add it and the error will go away.

If you are using maven as dependency Management tool, add the follwing lines to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Next jar is missing add `lucene-core-<version>.jar`

maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: sorry to bother you again @Jens , i am new to elastic search again some problem with the code please check the updated question .

Comment: @INFOSYS Looks like incompatible Version of `elasticsearch` and `google-collections`

Comment: how do i check that my elastic search verison is 5.4.0 and google collection is the same as you provided

Comment: Loocks like the ImmutableSet class is moved to guave. try to add the dependency `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
`

Comment: @INFOSYS you are using maven?

Comment: the error now is resolved but some thing new keeps popping up please check the question :(

Comment: @INFOSYS An other incompatiblility. It Looks like between `org.elasticsearch.transport` and `Lorg/elasticsearch/common/network`

Comment: do we have git repo for such project as i am not able to figure it out

Comment: @INFOSYS I do not know

Comment: This is the latest error , Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;